# Inserting row with Entity framework in table , having identity column without primary key

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have different case here,

[image]

in which **FromUserId** and **ToUserId** are Primary keys, and **InvitationId** is identity column,

Now I'm trying to insert

```
Invitation newInvitation = context.Invitations.CreateObject();                        
newInvitation.FromUserId = 100;
newInvitation.ToUserId = 1111;
newInvitation.AcceptToken = "stringvalue";
newInvitation.RejectToken = "stringvalue";
newInvitation.InvitedDate = DateTime.Now
newInvitation.ExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30f);
newInvitation.Status = "active";
context.SaveChanges();
```

we all know here we will get Exception like

```
"Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'InvitationId'. Table: 'Invitation'."
```

**Possible solution**
change **InvitationId** to primary key and refresh edmx file.

but is there any way to insert object with Entiry framework maintaing currect structure?

Comment: Why are FromUserId and ToUserId primary keys?  Someone can only invite someone else only once?  InvitationId looks like the correct primary key to me.

Comment: yes that is the plan, one user can invite other user only once

Comment: and what happens at the next event?  If Joe invited Ted to PartyA, then Joe can't invite Ted to PartyB.  Is that how it should be?

Comment: in this scenario, A user will invite only once to User B, after B accepts invitation, A will not invite to B again. there is no concept for Party.

Comment: ok then so if FromUserId and ToUserId are the primary key, why do you need an identity column?  The PK is all you need.

Comment: :) I am providing invitationID through webservice.